# Stack with 2 image not aligning flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this following image

[image: the design],

i am trying to show the icon at end of the image with stack but this what i am getting

[image]

Code i tried

```
      Stack(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 0,
                child: Image.network(
                  Urls.ImageUrl+vendorModel.cover_photo,
                  height: 80,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
                //radius: 52.5,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.favorite,color: Colors.red,),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `Expanded` widget

try this:

```
Row(
          children: [
            IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                    Urls.ImageUrl+vendorModel.cover_photo,
                    height: 80,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    color: Colors.red
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 8,),
            Column(children: [
              Text('text1'),
              Text('text2'),
              Text('text3'),
              Text('text4')
            ],mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,)
          ],
        )
```

Comment: it's still same,also throws `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget`,i am using `Stack` in row widget ,when i remove Stack there is no error,but i need stack to show image,is there any way @farouk osama

Comment: The parent of the Stack widget must have specific dimensions

Comment: I gave certain height and width now it's at the end but not in bottomRight,it's on left@farouk osama

Comment: I modified my answer, take a look at it